# How to hide a 'subtab': flexipage:tab

Tags: lightning

I have added a "sub tab" in a lightning flexipage. It contains a related list. I see it in the metadata like this:

```
      <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>Facet-4d465c3a-9791-4035-bdb2-2376d181ea93</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Practice Management Guides</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
```

How can I set it to "hidden" ?

Hide the tab that says "Practice Management Guide"

[image]

Comment: Nvm, I'm just going to comment it out.

Comment: seems legitimate

Comment: Actually that didn't work any suggestions ?

Comment: are you talking about hiding the subtab in a tab for a lightning page layout? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to take a screen shot at work tomorrow, it one of the tabs next to the details section.

Comment: @sanketkumar ^^^^^^^